# Writing IP address to file

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd, ip

Is there any simple command to write the ip-address into a file?

I know how to write in a file, but is there a sysvar or something!?

Comment: I think you're making a dangerous assumption when you say *the ip-address*. Many computers have more than one ip address since they have multiple network adapters, so make sure that whatever you do supports multiple IPs.

Comment: in case you need to see your external IP address (the one your model/router is assigned) not your local LAN's ip address see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669330/windows-batch-how-to-get-the-external-ip-into-a-batch-file-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipconfig | find "IP Address" > out.txt`

You still need to extract the IP Address from "IP Address.............: 0.0.0.0" and trim any whitespace.

Comment: Bear in mind also there may be more than one IP address, if you have more than one network adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest i can think of:

```
ipconfig > file
```

Comment: yeah, but do you know how to get ONLY the ip-address? *hm*

Comment: @fuzi: you could do something like `ipconfig | find "IPv4" > file` and then `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %i in (file) do echo %i >> ip.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@echo on

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IP Address"') do set ip=%%b

set ip=%ip:~1%

echo %ip%
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 machines:

```
ipconfig | findstr /b /c:"   IPv4" > output.txt
```

There are three whitespace characters between the opening quotation mark and IPv4 since that line technically begins with whitespace.  I am unaware of a way to strip that prior to the findstr command.

Remember that, even though it's *technically* regular expressions, the Windows command line doesn't parse them the same way as, say, C# or whatever.  There's a list of the acceptable sequences/wildcards (marked for XP, but it worked for me in a Win7 environment) [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).

Took me a little trial and error, but this gets you ONLY the lines for assigned IPv4 addresses, and not the "Autoconfigured" stuff that clutters the results of other findstr iterations.

Answer (score 1):

here is a vbs script that will do the job.  Note that this is for the external IP address.  Just look above for an internal/local ip address.

here is the code.  just create a text document, paste this, and rename it to something.vbs

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim ipLog, objHTTP, strHTML, varStart
Dim varStop, strIP, strCurrIP, objFSO
Dim txtFile, strLine, objShell

' Log for tracking external IP addresses
ipLog = "ExternalIP.txt"

' Get current external IP address from web
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Call objHTTP.Open("GET", "http://checkip.dyndns.org", False)
objHTTP.Send()
strHTML = objHTTP.ResponseText

' Extarct IP from HTML if HTML was recieved
If strHTML <> "" Then
    varStart = InStr(1, strHTML, "Current IP Address:", vbTextCompare) + 19
    If varStart Then varStop = InStr(varStart, strHTML, "</body>", vbTextCompare)
    If varStart And varStop Then strIP = Mid(strHTML, varStart, varStop - varStart)
Else
    strIP = "Unavailable"
End If
' Remove preceeding or trailing spaces
strCurrIP = Trim(strIP)

' Check for log file and last log entry
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not (objFSO.FileExists(ipLog)) Then 
    ' If log file doesn't exist create it
    Set txtFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(ipLog, True)
    strIP = ""
Else
    ' Get last external IP address entry from log file
    Set txtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ipLog, ForReading)
    Do Until txtFile.AtEndOfStream
       strLine = txtFile.ReadLine
       If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
          strIP = strLine
       End If
    Loop

End If
txtFile.Close

' Extarct last external IP from log file entry
If strIP <> "" Then
    varStart = 1
    varStop = InStr(varStart, strIP, ",", vbTextCompare) - 1
    If varStop Then strIP = Mid(strIP, varStart, varStop - varStart)
    ' Remove preceeding or trailing spaces
    Trim(strIP)
 Else
    strIP = "Unavailable"
 End If

' Copy IP to clipboard
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "CMD /C ECHO " & strCurrIP & " | CLIP", 2

' Check if external IP has changed
If strCurrIP = strIP Then
' If unchanged display IP
    MsgBox "External IP:  " & strCurrIP & " is unchanged"
Else
    ' If changed log to file and display IP
    Set txtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ipLog, ForAppending)
    txtFile.Write(strCurrIP & vbTab & vbCrLf)
    txtFile.Close
    MsgBox "External IP:  " & strCurrIP & vbCrLf & "This IP address has been logged"
End If

' Clear variables
Set ipLog = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing
Set strHTML = Nothing
Set varStart = Nothing
Set varStop = Nothing
Set strIP = Nothing
Set strCurrIP = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set txtFile = Nothing
Set strLine = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I do not take credit for this script, I just found it in a folder on my computer that I hadn't touched in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Just added a little to also display the gateway (your router) and ping to see if your DNS is working:

```
@echo off

:ipaddress
::Get IP address and save it to ip
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IP Address"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%

:gateway
::Get Gateway address and save it to gateway
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Gateway"') do set gateway=%%b
set gateway=%gateway:~1%


echo IP address is %ip%
echo You router address is %gateway%
pause

cls
ping %gateway% -a
pause

:end
```

Comment: Which IP address? Which gateway?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
PowerShell.exe -Command "(Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()" >> ipToFile.txt
```