# Windows Batch - How to get the external IP into a batch-file variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip

I am making a program that checks if a user's IP is a certain IP address.

Currently, I created a successful internal IP version:

```
@echo off
set userIp=192.168.90.100
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('route print ^| find " 0.0.0.0"') do set localIp=%%i
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do set thisip=%%a
goto :Check

:Check
if %localIp%==%userIp% goto :Good
if %thisip%==%userIp% goto :Good
goto :Bad
```

And I am trying to make the same thing that works with external IPs.

I researched online, and here is what I got so far.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a IN ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com ^| findstr /IC:"Address"') do if /i %%a=="10.11.12.13" goto :Good
goto :Bad
```

I need a bit of help on how to fix this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With pure batch/already present tools:
**EDIT: changed the batch to properly handle also IPv6 addresses**

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%B
Echo External IP is : %ExtIP%
```

[Reference](https://superuser.com/a/722397/639112)

Another one with powershell:

```
@Echo off
For /f %%A in (
  'powershell -command "(Invoke-Webrequest "http://api.ipify.org").content"'
) Do Set ExtIP=%%A
Echo External IP is : %ExtIP%
```

And another slightly different powershell variant:

```
@Echo off
For /f %%A in (
  'powershell -nop -c "(Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json).IP"'
) Do Set ExtIP=%%A
Echo External IP is : %ExtIP%
```

Comment: Guess I gotta updated my version of powershell to version 3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Is it possible (and how) to retrieve the IPv4 address when getting an IPv6 address?

Comment: @script'n'code The topic is about **external** IP addresses, so it depends on your internet connection if you have an IPv4 or IPv6 address (or both like me ATM) The 1st batch above didn't handle IPv6 addresses well cutting after the first colon. **changed** If both IPv4/6 are present the 1st batch will show IPv6 while the 2nd shows IPv4.

Answer (score 3):

To get your public IP without additional parsing do this:

curl "http://api.ipify.org"

EDIT:

This version is more reliable across windows language versions:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims== " %%A in ('
nslookup -debug myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|findstr /C:"internet address"
') do set "ext_ip=%%A"
```

Comment: I am running Windows 10 and It says: " 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " I want it to be able to work on most Windows versions including my own.

Comment: Curl now IS a part of WIndows 10

Comment: For Windows 7 compatibility you would want to use nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

First it seems there is a `.` too much after the first `.com`.

Second when using your command with simply `google.com` and `echo %a` I get the following:

`"  xx.xx.xx.x"` **without** the quotes and with two leading spaces!

So your if will **never** be true!

Change it to something like this: `if "%%a"=="  xx.xx.xx.x" Goto:good` and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the code it is supposed to be? I don't know what you mean with simply google.com, because it gives me an error when I run it. Also, does this work on all windows versions?

Comment: I had to test on my own as well and I ran `nslookup google.com` to check what output I get. You will have to change nothing except your if-condition as stated above. And as long as `nslookup` is present, this should work on all windows versions. Code will follow later as I am busy right now.