# How to check status of internet connection in batch script

Tags: batch-file, internet-connection

How do you check if an internet connection is active with a batch script?
In the example below, it *echo*s if the battery level is below or above `50%`.

```
for /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%A in ('wmic PATH Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining  /Format:list ^| FINDSTR "[0-9]"'
)DO (set by=%%B)
if %by% GEQ 50 (echo "Battery is above 50") else (echo "Battery is under 50")
```

How do I do something similar with active Wi-Fi connection?
E.G: 
`if %netcon% EQU 0 (echo "no connection") else (echo "active connection")` or something of the like.

I also don't want to use the errorlevel output of `ping google.com -n 1 -w 1000` etc., as at work, it fails (They force us to use a proxy).
***So, is the internet connection status stored somewhere in the system accessible by a batch file (eg. WMIC)?***

Context: I want to validate that an internet connection is active before sending a POST to harvardgenerator.com

Comment: What will you do with the information (I assume more than just echoing)? Because bear in mind that whatever result you get, *may no longer be true* by the time you act upon it.

Comment: If the connection is active, it will go to a section where it sends requests to a web server, or else just report the lack of connection and quit

Comment: Right, so at the time that you check for a connection, it's there. By the time your code attempts to send something to the web server, the connection has dropped. You need to write code that will cope with *that* problem *anyway*, so you may as well go straight ahead with making your requests and dealing with any errors that can occur at *any* time during those requests. The network is outside of your control. (Also, of course, just because a connection is available doesn't mean that the web server is reachable or will not error)

Comment: Well, I'm just assuming that the connection doesn't drop out within the minute :D. So going by just time of checking, and not worrying about any changes that _may_ occur, is it possible?

Comment: Wlan  connection and Internet connection are a different pair of shoes, the latter implies the other. If you can [get your external ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677062/6811411) you ***have*** an internet connection.

Comment: Check my edit, and why the downvote? I want to know what i did wrong before i post anything else on this website

Comment: If you have Vista or greater, there is a COM component called [Network List Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370803(v=vs.85).aspx) that has an interface called [INetworkConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370751(v=vs.85).aspx) that will tell you whether or not you have internet access (just like the Network and Sharing center does).  Good luck getting at that info from a batch file, though.